# Connect and run a command on a local Linux server via VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible, via VBScript to connect to a local Linux server via SSH, issue a single command and then disconnect?

I searched online but couldn't see any examples on doing this but didn't see any examples of doing so.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: Maybe look here: http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/ssh_exec.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), especially Plink:

> Plink (PuTTY Link) is a command-line connection tool similar to UNIX
>   ssh. It is mostly used for automated operations, such as making CVS
>   access a repository on a remote server.

If you are lucky, you don't even need to wrap the Plink call in a VBScript program.

Comment: It's not possible to do it using VBScript without a third-party program?